How to give a bootstrap table a minimum height, while still preserving table row height to be minimal?
so my my problem is this. I have a bootstrap table which I have to give a minimum height. The problem now is that my table rows are taking all the available space left. So when I only have one row, its filling the whole space. When the table is half full, it also looks bad, because the rows are taking as much space as possible. When the table is full, it looks awesome
Here's a snippet:
<table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
                //...a bunch of ths, loaded dynamically
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
             <tr>
                //...a bunch of td's, loaded dynamically
                //here's the actual problem, the td's are taking as much space as
                //they can and not just the space they need
             </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>

Here's how I made the table the minimum height:
.table  {
    flex-grow: 1;

    & > thead > tr { // dirty fix. else, the table head would gain a lot of height
      height: 1px;
    }
  }

I've tried a lot of fixes, including ones with manipulating the display attributes, but cannot really find one that keeps table heads arranged to the rows. Please keep in notice that this table is being used all across my website so I cannot change the whole structure, only some CSS additions should be applied. Here's the one fix that almost worked, the only problem here was the alignment of ths and tds
& > .table {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    & > thead {
      display: table;
    }
    & > tbody {
      display: table;
      & > tr {
        height: auto;
      }
    }
  }

Did anyone encounter a problem like this in the past? Would be really grateful for any help.

Not sure how you could expect a different result; this is simply not how tables work. Stretching the cells, so that the whole available width and height are filled, just is how tables work. And forget about messing with the display property - as soon as you do that, you rob the table of its "table behavior" - including stuff like columns being properly aligned below their headers.

You could insert an "empty" last row into the tbody, and then apply the same trick you used on the header rows, for all rows except that last one - & > tbody > tr:not(:last-child) { height: 1px; }

Depending on what exact formatting you need to apply (mostly regarding borders), that last tbody "row" could also be inserted as an empty pseudo element (then the 1px height hack needs to be applied to all real table rows, without the :last-child exception.)

Perhaps it could work if you put the table in a <div> ..... </div> tag? Give that tag the minimum height and just let the table do its thing.

@C3roe You are right. Messing with the display property is not an option. Your solution worked out just fine, I used javascript to append an empty  element to tbody. And applied a height of 1px to every  except the last one.
Thank you very much for your time.

@m0t0rhektor - If it's important to you, I suggest that you check that your solution works correctly in Firefox. Firefox's and Chromium's behaviour is significantly different here.
